# Get date for N days before

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I found some problem with my bat script which is dedicated to find date in format YYYYMMDD, but still can't figure out reason of such behavior.

Script code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SetLocal

SET CmdFile="C:\cmd.ini"
SET StartDate = ""

call:getDate %1 StartDate

IF EXIST %CmdFile% del %CmdFile%

(
    echo RangeBegin=20%StartDate%
) > %CmdFile%

:getDate
set day=%~1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "data=%YYYY:~2,4%%mm%%dd%"
set "%~2=%data%"
goto:eof

endlocal
```

So, I call a script like `makecmd.bat -10` and expect to find a new file in `C:\` drive named `cmd.ini` with following context:

```
RangeBegin=20170627
```

But got this:

```
RangeBegin=20,4~4,2~6,2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't `set` a function argument, instead, you *should* set it to another variable.

Comment: @SteveFest can you please explain a bit wider if it is possible

Comment: @SteveFest - If you're talking about the `set "%~2=%data%` line, that's actually perfectly valid and it's used for returning values from functions. The script is breaking because they aren't using delayed expansion correctly.

Comment: @SomethingDark Sometimes my eyes and brain are malfunctioning, my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some more errors in the code:

```
SET StartDate = ""
```

- Will assign `""` (leading space) to a variable named `StartDate`
  with a trailing space
- The`IF EXIST %CmdFile% del %CmdFile%` is superfluous as the following
  echo will overwrite the file nevertheless.
- As program flow will reach the label `:getDate` there should be a
  `goto :eof` or an `Exit /b` placed before.
- In the vbscript the variable `d` isn't used, why define it?
- The vbscript already creates a date in the format `yyyyMMdd` why
  split it up and then **wrongly** put together in the remaining batch part?
- The last line `endlocal` can never be reached.

Albeit I'm in doubt if a batch should have write access to the root of drive c: this batch version should do:

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET CmdFile="C:\cmd.ini"
SET "StartDate="
call:getDate %1 StartDate

 > %CmdFile% echo RangeBegin=%StartDate%

Goto :Eof
:getDate
set day=%~1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "%~2=%%a"
```

Sample ouput:

```
> SO_44973476.cmd -10
> type cmd.ini
RangeBegin=20170627
```

If you don't mind using PowerShell from batch, this will give the very same result:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f %%a in (
  'powershell -NonI -NoP -C "(get-date).AddDays(%~1).ToString(\"yyyyMMdd\")"'
) Do >"C:\cmd.ini" Echo RangeBegin=%%a
```